# Django upgrade, Import Error and conflicting package names

Tags: python, django, import

I have an older django project (created while 1.3 was hot) which I'm attempting to convert to the latest Django 1.6.

The new directory strucure was converted to the new way, and the project name was removed from all imports (`from myproject.api import x` became `from api import x`)

```
myproject/
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    api/
        __init__.py
        resthandler.py
    platforms/
        __init__.py
        plat1/
            __init__.py
            handlers.py
            api/
                __init__.py
```

The problem is that platforms/plat1/handlers attempts to import from /api/resthandler.py

from api.resthandler import RestHandler

But as there is already an api at a lower level, it fails with an ImportError as resthandler is not there, its 2 levels up and one down in /api. 
I've tried returning the project level to imports, tried relative imports, nothing helps. I can't seem to import /api from within platforms/plat1/. I'd go and change the entire structure but I wanted to see if I'm missing something before I take that route.

Comment: does api/__init__.py has anything on it?

Comment: no, /api/__init__.py is empty. The internal one has code though (quite a bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the solution to this was to import absolute_imports from **future**.

`from __future__ import absolute_imports`

that way all imports are absolute from root, unless relative imports are explicitly specified using the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

It is the behaviour of python not django. U may change the name of the folder. The rest will be workaround and may couse more trouble.

Comment: Yes I know its Python and not Django but I was hoping to do this migration with the minimum amount of changes. I will change the dir name if I can't find an elegant solution for sure, but I have got to try first :)

Comment: Or move /api inside myproject/

Comment: If u want to make something out of the python way it will not be elegant be sure. We have an idiom in here. There is only one true way to god (:

Comment: From what I can tell, this is all a side effect of having the django 'project' move from being at the top level of the project into a directory within it. I don't see it as going 'against' the python way, just trying to see where it was lost in all this migration.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> The problem is that platforms/plat1/handlers attempts to import from /api/resthandler.py
>
> from api.resthandler import RestHandler

do you want to import the root level "api" or the current folder one?
If you want the current folder one, does this work?:

```
from .api import resthandler.RestHandler as Plat1RestHandler
```